# Can't install ggplot in latest version of Rstudio

Tags: ggplot2, rlang, install.packages

I've tried using `install.packages("tidyverse")` and `install.packages("ggplot2")` but both end in non-zero exit status.

Part of the error reads

```r
Error i loadNamespace(i, c(lib.loc, .libPaths()), versionCheck = vI[[i]]) : 
  namespace 'rlang' 1.0.2 is being loaded, but >= 1.0.6 is required
```

I've tried to `remove.packages("rLang")` and `install.packages("rLang")`, but it just re-installs v_1.0.2 and the non-zero exit continues. I also tried `install.packages("https://cran.r-project.org/src/contrib/Archive/rlang/rlang_1.0.6.tar.gz", repo=NULL, type="source")`, but it fails with `'make' not found`.

I've also tried uninstalling Rstudio and installed an earlier version, but it doesn't change anything.

I found something similar in a different post, which was resolved by using `update.packages()`, which I did, but it didn't solve the issue.

Comment: Can you also share which version of R you are using?

Comment: I was using 4.0.3.

I uninstalled both Rstudio and R, restarted the computer and installed both R(v_4.3.0) and Rstudio(2023.03.1-446 again), then *update.packages()* and then install.package("ggplot2") worked.